# Changing object properties from method (Best Practise)

Tags: c#, methods, parameter-passing

I have a question for you. What is best practise to change object properties in method. Let's assume that I have a method like this:

```
    public void ChangeThis(MyObj myobj)
    {
        myobj.Prop = 5;
    }
```

Isn't better to return that object like we want to show that we change something?

```
    public MyObj ChangeThis(MyObj myobj)
    {
        myobj.Prop = 5;
        return myobj;
    }
```

What is best practise to change object properties from methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

While the first case appears more often, the second one is a useful, when you want to combine method calls in chain:

```
myObject
  .ChangeThis()
  .ChangeThat()
  .ChangeSomethingElse();
```

I think, [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a very good example:

```
sb
  .AppendLine("1")
  .AppendChar('2')
  .AppendLine()
  .ToSting();
```

The same API have model configuration [classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.stringpropertyconfiguration%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) from Entity Framework:

```
Property(_ => _.Name)
    .HasColumnName("name")
    .HasMaxLength(64)
    .IsRequired();
```

Thus, sometimes this is **very** convenient way to call methods.
Imagine, how the code from above would look in 1st case:

```
  sb.AppendLine("1");
  sb.AppendChar('2');
  sb.AppendLine();
  sb.ToSting();
```

Sadly, isn't it?

Comment: First method with `StringBuilder` is better for me. Now I know that is depends of my needs. And there's no "better" way to do such things.

Answer (score 3):

The second method is bad as it is ambiguous as to whether a new instance of the object is created with the changed property or if the current instance is returned.

I would only use the second method if my objects were immutable.

The name of the method, `ChangeThis`, implies that the object is mutable, but by returning an object it suggests that they are not.

Comment: Disagree. Immutability isn't a criteria in this case. It would be terrible, if *mutable* `StringBuilder` wouldn't have such API.

Comment: @Dennis - I didn't know `StringBuilder` had this interface. I'm actually now horrified and I feel dirty now. It really means that `StringBuilder` needs to be very carefully encapsulated.

Comment: But I suppose that I changed something and returning object that I just modify.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it obvious that the internal state of the object was changed, do it so by choosing a proper name for the method, and by adding proper XML documentation.

I don't think this is a good enough reason to return the object back to the client and, quite honestly, it's confusing. Are you returning a new object? Or is it the same object that was passed as a parameter? However, if the type is immutable, then you *should* return it.